# Update v-for list items that depend on a promise, after promise resolves.

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list that iterates through an array of objects, and generates list items that depends on the current object.

A calculation has to be made with the object as parameter, which returns a promise. The issue is that when the list is rendered, it only has access to the promise object (which is pending), and doesn't update once it resolves.

```
<md-list id="orderList">
        <md-list-item v-for="order in orders" :key="order.id" @click="orderDialog(order)">
            {{ asyncFunction(order) }}
        </md-list-item>
 </md-list>
```

How can I get the desired behaviour?

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? Are you saying that you have the orders data, but that part of that data is loaded later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work for you. Basically, store the asynchronous response in a reactive array when the promise returns. Since it's reactive, the promise response will automatically be displayed once each promise return.

```
<template>
    <md-list id="orderList">
        <md-list-item v-for="(order,i) in orders" :key="order.id" @click="orderDialog(order)">
            <template v-if="typeof asyncDataHolder[i] !== 'undefined'">
                {{asyncDataHolder[i]}}
            </template>
        </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    orders: [],
    asyncDataHolder: []
  },
  created() {
    // sample load orders
    sampleLoadOrdersData().then(response => {
      this.orders = response;
      this.loadAsyncData();
    });
  },
  methods: {
    loadAsyncData() {
      // async await version
      this.orders.map(async (order, i) => {
        const response = await asyncFunction(order);
        this.$set(this.asyncDataHolder, i, response);
      });

      // normal promise version
      this.orders.map((order, i) => {
        asyncFunction(order).then(response => {
          this.$set(this.asyncDataHolder, i, response);
        });
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: This makes sense, and it seems to be reacting to asyncDataHolder updates as it should. However, for some reason the code in "mounted()" doesn't work. The code block inside the ".map" function does not run! Any idea why this might be? To clarify: I put a console.log just above "const response = await.." and it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Maybe your babel transpiler doesn't work with async await. Maybe I made some syntax error that I'm unaware of. Anyway, I've updated the answer with a `normal promise version`. pls try ?

Comment: Still doesn't work. I checked that this.orders is indeed an array and has objects at the time of running the code....
I also checked that the mounted() method runs.

Comment: I'm unable to deduce what's wrong here? Is .map not running at all? Any error you are getting? I would understand the situation more if you are able to create a minimal example in js fiddle

Comment: It doesn't seem to be running, which is very strange. I'm not even getting any errors. I store the array as such:

data()  {
    return {
        orders: []
    }
}

perhaps Vue does some magic to the array so it's not the type of array object I think it is?

Comment: @Alexmedkex oh  so orders is empty in the beginning, that's why .map does nothing. because orders is empty. how and when did you load data into orders ?

Comment: Right, but I load data into orders in "created()". I also print the contents of "orders" before the .map call and it is clearly not empty.

I tried to recreate it here: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/249499/

In this example it seems to run the .map method though, but the data doesn't update.

Comment: @Alexmedkex even though mounted happens after created, mounted can still happen before the orders data is loaded. I have updated the answer. basically it means calling `asyncFunction` only after `orders` value has been assigned

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks a bunch! I should have given a larger context in the original question, sorry for that.

Comment: I also want to add that updating an index in an array will not trigger a re-render in vue, so the code above will not update the DOM. I solved it by using array.push instead.

Comment: @Alexmedkex oh right. my bad. Thanks for informing.

Comment: @Alexmedkex i just realized that `.push` is problematic as well. because the order of the async response is not always the same as the order of async request. For e.g. , the 2nd request may respond sooner than the 1st request. This will mess up the order of `asyncDataHolder`. Please use [this.$set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set), for e.g. `this.$set(this.asyncDataHolder, i, response);` .  This will trigger the re-render properly while maintaining the correct index for each response.